# Multicol problem with line between in different parts of document

Tags: multicol, multicolumn

I use multicols package which is applied in different part of my document. I want this part A has a line between two columns, but in part B I don't want it has the line between columns. What should I do ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\section{PartA}
\begin{multicols}{2}
   Some Text         %I want this section has a line between
\end{multicols}

\section{Part B}
\begin{multicols}{2}
   Some text         % This section doesn't need a line between
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}` to achieve no vertical separator:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\section{PartA}
\begin{multicols}{2}
   Some Text         %I want this section has a line between
\end{multicols}

\section{Part B}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
   Some text         % This section doesn't need a line between
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]